# Adding a user to WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We're integrating our asp.net MVC client with WSO2's Identity Server v5.8.0. 
Below are the steps we've followed: 

1) Created a Service provider for our MVC application & configured Inbound authentication with OAuth/OpenID configuration, also configured Inbound provisioning with primary user store.

2) In our MVC application, we've set up a WSO2 configuration using OWIN's WSO2 NuGet package with the generated client-id & client-secret from the service provider. 

3) We've configured MongoDB as our primary user store.

Now we're trying to add a user using SCIM2 API (https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users). Below is the response we're getting:

```
{"schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"],"detail":"Cannot add user through scim to user store . SCIM is not enabled for user store WSO2.COM","status":"500"}
```

I've even changed below config in user-mgt.xml

```
<Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
```

What else do we need to configure? Is there any other way to add user in WSO2 Identity server apart from using SCIM APIs?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are having two user stores the primary user store and a secondary user store named **wso2.com**. By adding the

```
<Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
```

To the user-mgt.xml you are enabling SCIM2 to the primary user store. Not the secondary user store. But from the API you are adding the user to the secondary user store. Since you havent enabled SCIM in the secondary user store you are getting this error. You have two options.

1) Add the user to PRIMARY user store

By analyzing the error that you are getting the user name of the user that you are trying to add should be some thing like

```
WSO2.COM/Abhishek
```

Change this to

```
Abhishek
```

2) Enable SCIM2 in the secondary user store

Log in to the management console and click list in  User Stores sub menu under identity menu.
The User Store Management page opens. There should be a user store named WSO2.COM
Click on edit. Click on advanced tick the enable scim

[image]

Reference: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Using+the+SCIM+2.0+REST+APIs

Comment: {"schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"],"detail":"Error in adding the user: kimjackson to the user store. Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block when called by method addUser with 6 length of Objects and argTypes [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Object, class [Ljava.lang.String;, interface java.util.Map, class java.lang.String, boolean]","status":"500"}

Comment: Request: 
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"schemas\":[],\"created\": \"2020-03-16T14:36:38.482Z\",\"name\":{\"familyName\":\"jackson\",\"givenName\":\"kim\"},\"userName\":\"kimjackson\",\"password\":\"kimwso2\",\"emails\":[{\"primary\":true,\"value\":\"kim.jackson@gmail.com\",\"type\":\"home\"},{\"value\":\"kim_j@wso2.com\",\"type\":\"work\"}]}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

Comment: The error you are getting is a generic one hence please enable org.wso2.carbon.user.core debug logs and reproduce the issue then attach the logs https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/monitoring-logs/#enable-logs-for-a-component

Comment: TID: [-1234] [] [2020-03-18 16:18:49,368]  WARN {org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain} -  Application {http://resources.provider.scim2.identity.carbon.wso2.org/}UserResource has thrown exception, unwinding now 
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
 at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
 at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)

Comment: TID: [-1234] [] [2020-03-18 16:18:49,370]  WARN {org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain} -  Exception in handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSDefaultFaultOutInterceptor@474aab3f 
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
 at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
 at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.common.impl.SCIMUserManager.createUser(SCIMUserManager.java:186)
 at org.wso2.charon3.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceManager.create(UserResourceManager.java:153)
 at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.provider.resources.UserResource.createUser(UserResource.java:120)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

Comment: TID: [-1234] [] [2020-03-18 16:18:49,373] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [SCIM2Servlet] in context with path [/scim2] threw exception 
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.common.impl.SCIMUserManager.createUser(SCIMUserManager.java:186)
 at org.wso2.charon3.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceManager.create(UserResourceManager.java:153)
 at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.provider.resources.UserResource.createUser(UserResource.java:120)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: [2020-03-18 16:18:49,256]  WARN {AUDIT_LOG}-  Initiator=admin@carbon.super Action=Add-User Target=kimjackson Data={"Claims":{"http://wso2.org/claims/userid":"19b46d2f-2888-499c-a19a-0857abf26d4f","http://wso2.org/claims/username":"kimjackson","http://wso2.org/claims/created":"2020-03-18T10:48:49.183Z","http://wso2.org/claims/modified":"2020-03-18T10:48:49.183Z","http://wso2.org/claims/emails.home":"kim.jackson@gmail.com","http://wso2.org/claims/location":"https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users/19b46d2f-2888-499c-a19a-0857abf26d4f","http://wso2.org/claims/lastname":"jackson"

Comment: ,"http://wso2.org/claims/emails.work":"kim_j@wso2.com","http://wso2.org/claims/resourceType":"User","http://wso2.org/claims/givenname":"kim"}} Outcome=Success